# Rails ActiveRecord: How to use bind variables with double quotes on jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-injection, jsonb

I have a postgres jsonb query as follows:

```
Blog.where("upload_data @> '[ { \"name\": \"#{name}\" }]'")
```

Which works but breaks build because the excellent brakeman points out the possible sql injection risk. If I use bind variables:

```
Blog.where("upload_data @> '[ { \"name\": ? }]'", name)
```

It creates a sql query like:

```
WHERE upload_data @> '[ { "name": 'name' }]'
```

Note the single quotes - which is an invalid query

If I use single quotes I get:

```
WHERE upload_data @> "[ { 'name': 'name' }]"
```

which is invalid

I have tried a few other things but what I want is for the bind variable to evaluate to a string with double quotes:

```
WHERE upload_data @> '[ { "name": "name" }]'
```

Or a different solution - other than getting brakeman to skip the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't put parameter placeholders inside quoted strings.

The fact that Rails allows you to do that and substitutes a single-quoted string inside the single-quoted string indicates that Rails has failed (as usual) to understand rules of SQL.

But you can put a parameter placeholder in an expression, with other strings. I am not a regular PostgreSQL user, but I assume you can concatenate strings together to form a complete JSON literal:

```
Blog.where("upload_data @> '[ { \"name\": \"' || ? || '\"}]'", name)
```

You might find it makes your code more clear if you parameterize the whole JSON value. Use `%Q()` to avoid needing to backslash the literal double-quotes.

```
Blog.where("upload_data @> ?", %Q([ { "name": "#{name}" } ]))
```

Or to make sure to generate valid JSON, I'd put the expression in Ruby syntax, and then convert to JSON:

```
Blog.where("upload_data @> ?", JSON.generate( [{name: name}] ))
```

Comment: Of course, thanks. It never occurred to me to make the JSON the bound variable. Perfect.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!