# How to use PDO bindParam inside MySQL JSON_CONTAINS?

Tags: mysql, json, pdo, mysql-json

I'm trying to get the following to run:

```
$driverID = 123; 

$query = 'SELECT
*
FROM cars
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`data`, \'{"drivers": [{"driverID": ":driverID"}]}\');';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':driverID', $driverID);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

However, it always results in an empty match. Removing the parameter and inputting the value directly works fine.

I suspect there's an issue with the quotes but I can't quite figure it out - what I would need to modify to get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `"` around `:driverID`? (Not sure at all, but that seems awkward: how would the system understand this _string_ is actually a parameter?)

Comment: I mean if you want the param to be considered as a string, pass it as such: quotes are not part of JSON, they're part of the data's type. IMHO. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and yes I tried without quotes around `:driverID` - unfortunately the result is still empty.

Comment: The whole thing I meant (to be sure): 1/ remove quotes around the param 2/ declare `$driverID = "123";` (with quotes, if the JSON in DB is a string). If that doesn't work, well, I hope someone will provide you better insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never put a parameter placeholder inside string delimiters.

WRONG:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mycolumn = ':param'
```

RIGHT:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mycolumn = :param
```

A good workaround is to build the JSON string in your application code and then bind the whole JSON string to the parameter.

```
$driverID = 123; 
$obj = ['drivers' => [['driverId' => $driverID]]];
$json = json_encode($obj);

$query = 'SELECT
*
FROM cars
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`data`, :json);';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $statement->execute(['json'=>$json]);
```

Using `json_encode()` is a good way to ensure that the data is in valid JSON format. It protects you from making accidental syntax mistakes.

See a very similar case (though for PostgreSQL) here: [Rails ActiveRecord: How to use bind variables with double quotes on jsonb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175986/rails-activerecord-how-to-use-bind-variables-with-double-quotes-on-jsonb/49185164#49185164)

Comment: That's a great workaround, makes a lot of sense too. Thanks!